# Save long txt on google app engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to save a long string in the google cloud datastore (more than 500 chars).
I searched the web and found out I need to use `Text` instead of `String`, so I tried to do so.

I changed this:

```
CloudEntity newProfilePicture = new CloudEntity("profiles");
newProfilePicture.put(MainMenu.userNickName, dataToSave);
```

to this:

```
CloudEntity newProfilePicture = new CloudEntity("profiles");
Text dataText = new Text(dataToSave);
newProfilePicture.put(MainMenu.userNickName, dataText);
```

but the program crashes..

(If I save short strings, everything works fine)

NOTE - if it matters, the import for the `Text` I used is:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text
```

from a *jar* I downloaded (otherwise, eclipse isn't recognizes the `Text` type)

the logcat:

```
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3184
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:507)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudEntity.createCloudEntityFromEntityDto(CloudEntity.java:79)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackend.insert(CloudBackend.java:111)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync.access$0(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:87)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$1.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
06-15 16:36:49.710: E/AndroidRuntime(31005):    at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:402)
```

Any advices?
Please HELP! :O

Comment: more than 500 chars in the server?? is there any special reason for walking that path

Comment: one of your values in hashmap is null and you are inserting null into a hashmap object check your values before inserting it

Comment: @IllegalArgument, I am trying to save Image, so I encoded it to a string (the result - more than 500 chars).
For some reason, the Text value witch saved in the server is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:  https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/mobile-backend-starter-api-reference#cep

`Text` is not a supported data type for `CloudEntity`.  Supported data types are:

```
String           Up to 500 Unicode characters
Integer          Converted to BigDecimal when reading the value from backend
Double/Float     Converted to BigDecimal when reading the value from backend
Boolean          With true or false values
DateTime         com.google.api.client.util.DateTime object. is converted to a String when reading the value from backend
List/Map         java.util.List or java.util. Map object that can contain strings longer than 500 characters and child List/Map. The elements are not indexed on Datastore and cannot be used as a query filtering/sorting condition. Empty List/Maps are not stored on Datastore
null
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I used a List<Object> with only one element (the long string I wanted to save), and it works!
You are a KING!:)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put bytes into a String, if you want to save the image profile bytes use `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob` rather than `Text`.

Anyway, read this documentation to be more comfortable with datastore
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But, I have a Bitmap which I want to save, I am using a function which converts it to a String, and that works fine. 
The string I got (dataToSave) is converted to a Text by the line:
"Text dataText = new Text(dataToSave);"
so where I'm trying to put bytes into a String? I didn't get it..

Comment: Ok then are you sure your string doensn't exceed 1Mbytes (if it's the case, check if there are no encoding problems with the generated String, I think Text accepts Utf-8 encoding)

Comment: I tried to save the image as a blob, and tried to save a string with a little more than 500 chars as a Text. In both cases, the logcat shows null exception (as detailed at the question above).
Do you have any idea why? or what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Ok I don't know why then, I suggest you debug the code in android to understand why the value passed by createCloudEntityFromEntityDto is null. Also tell me, do you confirm it works with String but doesn't with Text? if it's the case, it should be normal since your code that saves to db should not be on the phone but on GAE. I don't get it, are you trying to use a GAE object to an android app?

Comment: (sorry I don't know the architecture of the endpoint, but it's open source, you can look there if Text is allowed)

Comment: Indeed I confirm it works with a String and not with a Text.
I just trying to use the Text (GAE object) in my app to Save a longer String. Didn't found another solution..

Comment: But it seems you are on the Android side, Text might not be supported there where you are (I'm only supposing). Download the source from the git repository and see what's going on inside, don't rely on the answers here, sometimes, nobody answers

Comment: thank you very much about the help!
It solved by the answer of @GAEfan